# On Linux/Debian should .bashrc have anything set for python/python3 and if so what?

Tags: debian, python, environment-variables

What should be in the `.bashrc` for python/python3 on Debian11/KDE?

To verify the environment variable is correct, what should `echo $PATH` display? `which python3` displays `/usr/bin/python3`.

Comment: Nothing in particular needs to be set. Why do you think anything should be there? What problem do you have?

Comment: I don't know why I had a path in there whose dir doesn't exist, had a commented out $PYTHONPATH I probably tried setting long ago, and because of what could be problems with python or python venv.

Comment: `PYTHONPATH` overrides or complements the `sys.path` variable which defines where Python looks for modules when you `import` something. The default should be fine out of the box, so there should be no requirement to set that for a correctly configured Python. You could, if you wanted to; but these days, probably use a virtual environment for anything fancy anyway.